# Jquery sortable on mobile + select text, href tag

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

i use this:

http://touchpunch.furf.com/

this is JQUERy for mobile sorting. It is good, but sortable elements with text or tag HREF don't working. When i clicked on link inside `<li>` element, nathing happens. PLS, can we help me?

Comment: Provide your code, or write a jsfiddler for that. That would help people to understand your problem better.

Comment: Hi, problem is this: http://touchpunch.furf.com/  when i try it in mobile, text isn't selectable.